# formData.set is not working as expected in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

formData.set() is not working as expected in react js. I am facing some issue while submit the form. FormData is still coming as empty object on handleSubmit. I think formData.set is not working in text editor as expected. formData.set is work correctly for input element but for text editor is not working.
Can somebody tell us what went wrong in this code ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "../../node_modules/react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const CreatePost = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    error: "",
    success: "",
    formData: "",
    title: "",
  });
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");

  const { formData, title } = values;

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, formData: new FormData() });
  }, []);

  console.log("formData ===> ", formData);

  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    let value = name === "title" && e.target.value;
    formData.set(name, value);
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value, formData, error: "" });
  };

  const handleBody = (e) => {
    setBody(e);
    formData.set("body", e); // problem might here
  };

  console.log("body", body);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("formData", formData); // formData -> {} empty object
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            placeholder="Enter Title"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("title")}
            value={title}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <ReactQuill
            placeholder="Write something amazing..."
            modules={CreatePost.modules}
            formats={CreatePost.formats}
            onChange={handleBody}
            value={body}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

CreatePost.modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: "1" }, { header: "2" }, { header: [3, 4, 5, 6] }, { font: [] }],
    [{ size: [] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    ["link", "image", "video"],
    ["clean"],
    ["code-block"],
  ],
};

CreatePost.formats = [
  "header",
  "font",
  "size",
  "bold",
  "italic",
  "underline",
  "strike",
  "blockquote",
  "list",
  "bullet",
  "link",
  "image",
  "video",
  "code-block",
];

export default CreatePost;
```